# Android:About AndEngine updateThread and uiThread

Tags: java, android, andengine

I recently explore on *AndEngine*. I write a simple test demo, in which I implement `IOnSceneTouchListener` and the scene registers a `TimerHandler` to change one `ChangableText`.
And I set the engine `runOnUpdateThread` **true**.

**So the problem is**: when I touched the scene a while, the activity paused and crashed. And the Logcat showed the same text as before:***"org.anddev.andengine.util.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1 was exhausted, with 1 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more."***

If anyone can solve my problem, so thankful I will be!

PS: my code

```
    public class TestActivity extends BaseGameActivity implements IOnSceneTouchListener, IOnMenuItemClickListener {
    ...
    ...
    private TimerHandler mTimeUpdateHandler = new TimerHandler(1.f, true, new ITimerCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onTimePassed(TimerHandler arg0) {
                runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (mElapsedText != null && mAttempts > 0) {
                            mElapsedText.setText("Time: "
                                    + (ParticlyActivity.this.mEngine.getSecondsElapsedTotal() - mCurrentTotalSeconds),
                                    false);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    ...
    ...

    // @Override
        public Engine onLoadEngine() {
            this.mCamera = new BoundCamera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
            final EngineOptions engineOptions = new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE,
                    new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), mCamera).setNeedsSound(true);
            engineOptions.getTouchOptions().setRunOnUpdateThread(true);
            this.mEngine = new Engine(engineOptions);
            return this.mEngine;
        }


    public Scene onLoadScene(){
    ...
                // Text
                mElapsedText = new ChangeableText(20, 12, this.mFont, "Time:00.00");
                mScene.getFirstChild().attachChild(mElapsedText);
                mScene.registerUpdateHandler(mTimeUpdateHandler);

    ...
    }

@Override
    public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(final Scene pScene, final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {
            if ((pSceneTouchEvent.isActionMove() || pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) && mAttempts < MaxBullets) {
                double angle = 0;
                if ((pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - StartX) == 0) {
                    angle = 90;
                } else {
                    angle = Math
                            .abs(Math.atan((StartY - pSceneTouchEvent.getY()) / (StartX - pSceneTouchEvent.getX())) / 3.14 * 180);
                }
                if (angle > 90) {
                    angle = 90;
                } else if (angle < 0) {
                    angle = 0;
                }
                mGun.setRotation((float) -angle);
                mGun.setStrength(pSceneTouchEvent.getX());
            } else if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionUp() && mAttempts < MaxBullets) {
...
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    }
```

TimerHandler:

```
private TimerHandler mTimeUpdateHandler = new TimerHandler(1.f, true, new ITimerCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onTimePassed(TimerHandler arg0) {
        runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (mElapsedText != null && mAttempts > 0) {
                    mElapsedText.setText("Time: " + (ParticlyActivity.this.mEngine.getSecondsElapsedTotal() - mCurrentTotalSeconds), false);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: so far now, I really can not clearly tell what's the different of UIThread & UpdateThread, anyone know it plz tell me. Thanks so much in advance!!!

Comment: You need to post more output from LogCat so that we know what the error is.

Comment: @JohnEye thanks for replying. I got "<TouchEvent> exausted with 1 not recycled ,allocated 4 more..." before i changed code "engineOptions.getTouchOptions().setRunOnUpdateThread(true);" to "engineOptions.getTouchOptions().setRunOnUpdateThread(false);"

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the problem, there has to be something else in the LogCat output. Can you just copy it all and put it for example on pastebin?

Answer (score 0):

UIThread is the one responsible for drawing , UpdateThread gets executed every frame 
if you need to change Text values , do that on the UpdateThread [just stay away from the UIThread in general]

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Now I write one TimerHandler (pasted that code above), how can I register that? Can you take that for an example?Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Why are you using a timer handler, TimerTask seems an easier option for me .. check this code where I implement a coolDown class
https://github.com/JiMMaR/Jimvaders-Tutorial/blob/master/src/com/wordpress/jimmaru/android/jimvaderstutorial/CoolDown.java

if you want to have this work periodically, you can schedule it again at the end of the run method